# Link transaction to sublist record

Tags: netsuite

I have a custom record which I set up as a sublist to be shown on an opportunity. The user is able to enter a new record in the opportunity using the new button. I see that the entered record stays with the Opportunity but I would also like it to move on to the estimate and then the sales order.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be achieved by one of the following approaches,

1. You can create a sublist-view for other related transactions where you want the sublist.
2. You can create reference fields on custom-record for other transactions and update record reference in it, when source record is transformed like Opportunity -> Estimate, Estimate -> Sales Order etc., and this field should have ***Record Is Parent*** checked.

**Note:** If you create a sublist-view, user won't be able to directly create a  new record from the sublist as there won't be *New* button available.